# Align strings in Html with different lengths

Tags: html, format

Inside an Html paragraph I need to compose a string in multiple lines in order to have the colons aligned in the different lines 
(using naturally a monospaced font).

```
ShortString      : 1.0
LoooongString    : 2.0
VeryloooongString: 3.0
```

I would need to set a fixed width before the colons: this width is the maximum of the 3 strings.

Comment: Have you considered using tables for this? Seems like you're displaying tabular-like data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example using `table` and minimal style.

```css
.data {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.data td:last-child:before {
  content: ': '
}
```

```html
<table class="data">
  <tr>
    <td>ShortString</td>
    <td>1.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LoooongString</td>
    <td>2.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>VeryloooongString</td>
    <td>3.0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful idea.

In the CSS file I would need to define a style which is valid for this table only, to not interfere with the other tables.
Supposing the name of the style is "stylenew", in the CSS I could put the first setting:

table.stylenew {
 font-family: monospace;
}

but I couldn't define the "last-child" propriety inside the same style in order to work.
Can you help me?

Comment: @vaiadubai I've updated my answer to show how to style based on a CSS class (I used `.data`). Hope this helps.